# "the title, the introductory clause," but "a table of contents"

Tags: articles

In the following paragraph:

> It’s standard for a contract to consist of the front of the contract,
> the body of the contract—what the parties are agreeing to—and the back
> of the contract. The front consists of the title, the introductory
> clause, any recitals, and the lead-in. In longer contracts, it might
> include one or more of a cover sheet, a table of contents, and an
> index of definitions.

Why does the author use "the" for title, but "a" for cover sheet?

Comment: Good spot, Damon.

Answer (score 1):

The elements identified by *the* are essential; every contract is expected to have them. The others are optional; the text says they *might* be included. As elements that may or may not exist, they only warrant the indefinite article.

Comment: I suspect that Cobuild have missed this specialist usage in their (100+ page) monograph on 'Articles': essential v possible